# Communication between modules locally

Tags: google-app-engine

I have App Engine application with several modules. And trying to send request from one module to another. For this purpose I'm using code described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Communication_between_modules).

The problem is that next code returns only one current module.

```
ModulesServiceFactory.getModulesService().getModules();
```

And when I'm trying to get module hostname, like this

```
ModulesServiceFactory.getModulesService().getVersionHostname(moduleName, moduleVersion)
```

I'm getting exception `com.google.appengine.api.labs.modules.InvalidModuleException: Given module is not known.`

All modules I'm launching with command
`mvn appengine:devserver`

Also there is pom.xml in root folder, which describes all modules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>myapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine_app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>appengine_app</name>

  <properties>
    <appengine.app.version>1.0</appengine.app.version>
    <appengine.target.version>1.9.32</appengine.target.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
    <module>module3</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```